# How to filter a list of dataframes based on a unique count of categorical factors in each dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr, lapply

I have a dataframe that I split into a list of dataframes based on a categorical variable in the dataframe:

```
list <- split(mpg, mpg$manufacturer)
```

I want to filter the list to only include dataframes where one of the categorical columns in each dataframe contain at least 5 unique factors, and remove those with less than 5.
I have tried lapply and filter over the dataset, but the result is filtering each dataframe, not the list entirely, as well as:
`filteredlist <- lapply(list, function(x) length(unique(x$class) >= 5))`
and am stumped.

Thanks, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `Filter` not `lapply`

Comment: ... which means you need to swap the `x=` and `f=` args. Try `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x$class) >= 5), list)`

Comment: Since you tagged [tag:dplyr], I can only assume that you need to do follow-on processing for which you'd prefer to use `dplyr`. It is generally better then to _not_ `split` it, instead `mpg %>% filter(n_distinct(class) >= 5, .by = manufacturer)` (though `mpg` doesn't have any such groups ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's take a look at how many unique classes there are:

```
sapply(list, \(x) length(unique(x$class)))
   #    audi  chevrolet      dodge       ford      honda    hyundai       jeep land rover    lincoln 
   #       2          3          3          3          1          2          1          1          1 
   # mercury     nissan    pontiac     subaru     toyota volkswagen 
   #       1          3          1          3          4          3
```

So, with this data, the `>= 5` isn't a great example because it will have 0 results. Let's do `>= 3` so we can expect a non-empty result.

```
## with Filter
filteredlist <- Filter(list, f = function(x) length(unique(x$class)) >= 3)
length(filteredlist)
# [1] 7

## or with sapply and `[`
sapply_filter = list[sapply(list, \(x) length(unique(x$class))) >= 3]
length(sapply_filter)
# [1] 7
```

Note that in your attempt `lapply(list, function(x) length(unique(x$class) >= 5))` you have a parentheses typo, you want `length(unique()) >= 5)` not `length(unique(...) >= 5))`

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! I think I was stuck on trying to use lapply and filtering, rather than focusing on the list as a whole, like you show. Greatly appreciate it!